# Ripples not showing with selectableItemBackground as foreground on a CardView with a Android 5.0 device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview, rippledrawable

I'm running this on a Nexus 5. Here's part of the code for my CardView:

```
        CardView cardView = new CardView(getActivity());
        cardView.setRadius(4);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
        lp.setMargins(32, 16, 32, 16);
        cardView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        cardView.setContentPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
        ...
        cardView.setForeground(selectedItemDrawable);
```

And here's how I get the selectedItemDrawable:

```
        int[] attrs = new int[] { R.attr.selectableItemBackground };
        TypedArray ta = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
        selectedItemDrawable = ta.getDrawable(0);
        ta.recycle();
```

When I tap the card, the ripple that's supposed to come with the selectedItemDrawable does not appear (it looks exactly the same as without the foreground set). I am running 5.0, so this seems strange, as the appcompat docs only say that it doesn't work with pre-Lollipop devices. Does anybody know why this is the case? Minimum API level is 16, targetting 21.

Comment: Are you sure, you don't have any view in cardview which is set to match_parent and has background of its own?

Comment: I have commented out any code that adds a view to the CardView, so that only the CardView is in the layout, and the results are the same. Setting that as the background to a LinearLayout with those properties in the CardView also doesn't do anything.

Comment: Indeed, when defining the CardView in XML with android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground", there's still no ripple effect.

Comment: I'm able to create the ripple with XML with: android:clickable="true" and the selectableItemBackground foreground, but I can't seem to recreate it in code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out that I was sharing my instance of the Drawable with multiple cardviews. This was resolved by returning a new instance using a getSelectedItemDrawable method:

```
    public Drawable getSelectedItemDrawable() {
        int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
        TypedArray ta = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
        Drawable selectedItemDrawable = ta.getDrawable(0);
        ta.recycle();
        return selectedItemDrawable;
    }
```

Then setting it as the foreground programatically:

```
        cardView.setForeground(getSelectedItemDrawable());
        cardView.setClickable(true);
```

Now I get the ripple effect on 5.0.

Comment: Confirmed, setForeground() is only available on API 23+ - the Android docs incorrectly have it listed as API Level 1.  AOSP bug report here - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186273.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried putting this directly on an image view and also on a frame layout containing the image view. Neither worked.

Comment: you have to also add android:clickable="true" on your cardView