# Add selectableItemBackground to CardView

Tags: android, android-xml, android-cardview

I want to set the foreground of my [CardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) to `?attr/selectableItemBackground`.

It work's when I declare the foreground in xml:

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

But I want to set the foreground programmatically. This doesn't work:

```
int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.color_a, R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
mColorA = ta.getColor(0, 0);
mSelectableItemBackground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, ta.getResourceId(1, 0));
ta.recycle();

...

cardView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
cardView.setClickable(true);
cardView.setForeground(mSelectableItemBackground);
```

However, retrieving the attributes works (mSelectableItemBackground contains a `RippleDrawable`), but the foreground doesn't change when I press on the Card.

Comment: I think I just found a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27474279/4752807 .. I too use the same instance on multiple cards.. I have to investigate and will update this question then.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30192562/4409409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I used the same Drawable with multiple Cards.

You have to retrieve a new Drawable for each Card.

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27474621/4752807).